# Datatool : automatically add a new entry / use

Tags: datatool

I am a newbie with latex

I have a file, just for  test, ListeEleves.csv

```
nom,prénom
Avogadro,Amédéo
Bohr,Niels
Copernic,Nicolas
Einstein,Albert
```

I would like to get

```
nom,prénom,ID,IDInitials
Avogadro,Amédéo,Avogadro-Amedeo,Avogadro-A
Bohr,Niels,Bohr-Niels,Bohr-N
Copernic,Nicolas,Copernic-Nicolas,Copernic-N
Einstein,Albert,Einstein-Albert,Einstein-A
```

my code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{datatool}
%\DTLsetseparator{;}
\usepackage{fp,pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen,multido}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{ListeEleves}{ListeEleves.csv}

\DTLforeach{ListeEleves}{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}{%début for each
\DTLforeachkeyinrow{\ItemLu}{%début de for each key in row
%\ifthenelse{\dtlcol >2}{\dtlbreak}{%on limite la lecture aux deux premières colonnes
%suppression des lettres accentuées
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{À}{A}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{à}{a}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Â}{a}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{â}{a}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{È}{E}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{è}{e}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{É}{E}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{é}{e}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Ê}{E}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ê}{e}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Î}{I}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{î}{i}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Ï}{I}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ï}{i}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Ü}{U}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ü}{u}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Û}{U}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{û}{u}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Ù}{u}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ù}{u}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{Ô}{o}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ô}{o}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{'}{}
\DTLsubstituteall{\ItemLu}{ }{}
%fin suppression des lettres accentuées
%}%
\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{1}{\FPset\NOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}
\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{2}{\FPset\PRENOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}
}%fin de for each key in row
\NOM \PRENOM
}%fin for each

\DTLdisplaydb{ListeEleves}

\end{document}
```

1) Is it a more easier way to encode lines `\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{1}{\FPset\NOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}` and `\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{2}{\FPset\PRENOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}`

2) I can not manage to automatically add a new entry/column with
`\DTLnewdbentry{ListeEleves}{ID}{\NOM-Prenom}` even `\dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow` or `\dtlreplaceentryincurrentrow`

3) `\DTLstoreinitials{\Ini}{\PRENOM}` does not work with a command name

Do you have any idée ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! Wouldn't it be easier to manipulate the file prior to processing with LaTeX?

Comment: This looks like a cross-post of [Datatool : automatically add a new entry](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27407)

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is it a more easier way to encode lines
>   `\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{1}{\FPset\NOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}` and
>   `\DTLifeq{\dtlcol}{2}{\FPset\PRENOM{\ItemLu}}{\relax}`

Yes, there is an easier way. I don't understand why you're iterating through all the keys when you have already accessed them in the assignment `{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}`. As far as I can tell, you're trying to strip the accents from these two values. This can be done as follows (since you're using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{ListeEleves}{ListeEleves.csv}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stripaccents}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\IeC##1{\@thirdofthree##1}%
  \protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}%
  \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{ListeEleves}{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}{%
  \stripaccents{\NOM}{\nom}%
  \stripaccents{\PRENOM}{\prenom}%
  \NOM \PRENOM
}

\DTLdisplaydb{ListeEleves}

\end{document}
```

> 2) I can not manage to automatically add a new entry/column with
>   `\DTLnewdbentry{ListeEleves}{ID}{\NOM-Prenom}` even
>   `\dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow` or `\dtlreplaceentryincurrentrow`

You already worked this one out in the [cross-post on LC](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27407). You need to switch on the expansion when adding values containing commands that need expanding:

```
\dtlexpandnewvalue

\DTLforeach{ListeEleves}{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}{%
  \stripaccents{\NOM}{\nom}%
  \stripaccents{\PRENOM}{\prenom}%
  \DTLappendtorow{ID}{\NOM-\PRENOM}%
}
```

> 3) `\DTLstoreinitials{\Ini}{\PRENOM}` does not work with a command name

The first argument of `\DTLstoreinitials` must be a string not a command as no expansion is performed. Since there's no `\Ini` in your code, I'm guessing you have the arguments the wrong way round here and that you want the initials stored in `\Ini`. So you need to do:

```
\expandafter\DTLstoreinitials\expandafter{\PRENOM}{\Ini}
```

The complete document is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{ListeEleves}{ListeEleves.csv}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stripaccents}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\IeC##1{\@thirdofthree##1}%
  \protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\def\noexpand#1{#2}}%
  \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dtlexpandnewvalue
\renewcommand*{\DTLafterinitials}{}

\DTLforeach{ListeEleves}{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}{%
  \stripaccents{\NOM}{\nom}%
  \stripaccents{\PRENOM}{\prenom}%
  \DTLappendtorow{ID}{\NOM-\PRENOM}%
  \expandafter\DTLstoreinitials\expandafter{\PRENOM}{\Ini}%
  \DTLappendtorow{IDInitials}{\NOM-\Ini}%
}

\DTLdisplaydb{ListeEleves}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result]

which replicates your requested data:

```
nom,prénom,ID,IDInitials
Avogadro,Amédéo,Avogadro-Amedeo,Avogadro-A
Bohr,Niels,Bohr-Niels,Bohr-N
Copernic,Nicolas,Copernic-Nicolas,Copernic-N
Einstein,Albert,Einstein-Albert,Einstein-A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\DTLforeach{ListeCompetencesEleves}{\nom=nom,\prenom=prénom}{%
\def\IdQuestion{}
\DTLforeachkeyinrow{\ItemLu}{%
\ifthenelse{\dtlcol >2}{\dtlbreak}{%
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ }{}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{'}{}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{.}{}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{-}{}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{À}{A}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{à}{a}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Â}{A}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{â}{a}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{È}{E}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{è}{e}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{É}{E}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{é}{e}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ê}{E}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ê}{e}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Î}{I}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{î}{i}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ï}{I}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ï}{i}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ü}{U}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ü}{u}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Û}{U}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{û}{u}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ù}{u}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ù}{u}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ô}{O}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ô}{o}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{Ö}{O}[\ItemLu]
\StrSubstitute{\ItemLu}{ö}{o}[\ItemLu]
   }%
\xdef\IdQuestion{\IdQuestion\ItemLu-}
}%
\DTLgetvalue{\NOM}{ListeCompetencesEleves}{\DTLcurrentindex}{\dtlcolumnindex{ListeCompetencesEleves}{nom}}%
\DTLgetvalue{\PRENOM}{ListeCompetencesEleves}{\DTLcurrentindex}{\dtlcolumnindex{ListeCompetencesEleves}{prénom}}%
\StrChar{\PRENOM}{1}[\Initiale]%
\def\Patronyme{\NOM~\Initiale}% 
\StrGobbleRight{\IdQuestion}{2}[\IdQuestion]%
\DTLappendtorow{IdQuestion}{\IdQuestion}%
\DTLappendtorow{Patronyme}{\Patronyme}%
}%
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?  This is just some uncompilable snippet of code.